# Enviar props mediante this.$router.push en Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue3, vue-router

Me gustaría saber como enviar props a un componente pero usando el método this.$router.push({path: 'contacto', props: {completedEmail: "example@email.com"}}).
No se envian correctamente las propiedades.

```
methods: {
   
    onSubmit(value) {

      let email = (value.target[0].value);
      
      this.$router.push({path: 'contacto', props: {completedEmail: "example@email.com"}})
    }
  },
```

La idea del código es escribir tu correo en la página home y cuando lo envíes que se envíe el correo como props a la página de contacto donde terminas de introducir el resto de datos de contacto.

En el router tengo configurado esto:

```
{
    path: '/contacto',
    name: 'contacto',
    props: {
      completedEmail: String
    },
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "contacto" */ '@/modules/contacto/views/ContactoView.vue')
  }
```

Y en el view de contacto recojo la propiedad de la siguiente manera:

```
<template>
  <Header :home="false" :imgProps="{alt: 'Piscina de madera en Francia', src: require('@/modules/contacto/assets/pexels-piscina.jpg')}" title="Contacto" />
  <Form :completedEmail="completedEmail" />
  <Footer />
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/Header.vue'
import Form from '../components/Form.vue'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'

export default {
  props: {
    completedEmail: String
  },
  components: { 
    Header,
    Form,
    Footer
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que intentas es navegación programática, y para el envió de props puedes usar el objeto `params: {}` como lo indica la documentación y asignar en tu componente los `props: true` para que puedas tomarlo:

Router:

```
{
    path: '/contacto',
    name: 'contacto',
    props: {
      true
    },
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "contacto" */ '@/modules/contacto/views/ContactoView.vue')
  }
```

Push:

`this.$router.push({name: 'contacto', params: {completedEmail: "example@email.com"}}) //Con name`

**Comentario**: Otra alternativa es usar `$emit()` con parámetro, donde usarías el método `onSubmit()` desde el componente contacto enviando el correo (como parámetro). Caso mayor usar un estado donde emplees pinia por ejemplo.